# Bad request on Query `FIND {aa-bb.cc.com} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Account`, maybe due to dash

Tags: soql, rest-api, webservices

Using salesforce webservices (REST API), this query works:

https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/search/?q=FIND%20%7Baabb%40cc.com%7D%20IN%20EMAIL%20FIELDS%20RETURNING%20Account

*URL decoded:* `FIND {aabb@cc.com} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Account`

But this query does not work (400 Bad request):

https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/search/?q=FIND%20%7Baa-bb%40cc.com%7D%20IN%20EMAIL%20FIELDS%20RETURNING%20Account

*URL decoded:* `FIND {aa-bb@cc.com} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Account`

So it seems a "dash" is not accepted, and result in a bad request response. But why? Did I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SOSL following characters are consider as special characters.

```
? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * : \ " ' + -
```

As you can see - is also special character you need to escape it.

You can use \ to escape - character. For Ex.

```
/services/data/v34.0/search?q=FIND+{aa\-bb@cc.com}+IN+EMAIL+FIELDS+RETURNING+Contact
```

This gives all contact with email id = "aa-bb@cc.com"

Here is refrance link of documentation for you: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm